# How to select templates

Tags: templates

We are running a conference, when sending a receipt to someone how do we select one of the stored templates which we have created e.g late payment?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

There is no way you can select template to replace the receipt/invoice that is send by Civi automatically. If you want to send a separate invoice/template for certain people than you will need to either write an extension to replace the template with user-driven message template or you can use Schedule reminder or Send Email activity.

1. **Extension**:

Implement [hook_civicrm_alterMailParams](https://docs.civicrm.org/dev/en/latest/hooks/hook_civicrm_alterMailParams/) in your extension to replace the message template based on $params parameter

2. Create Email Activity or bulk email to a group

You can use Email activity to send email with the help of [Civi-token](https://civicrm.org/extensions/nzcofuzioncivitoken) extension.

3. Schedule reminder

Add contact's to a group whom you want to send invoice, create a Contribution schedule reminder and use your template to send email.

HTH

Pradeep